# How to align imageView after change by button

Tags: java, android, imageview, alignment, buttonclick

I started learning making Android Apps, and I have stumbled upon a problem. 
I have made my app to change an imageView by a button

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttOK);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ring); // changes the image
```

so, now, when I click on the button, it changes an image.

The problem is, the original image was centered, and the image that replaces it is set on top left. I can't center it, or move it or anything. I guess I am missing a tiny detail somewhere.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.maxa.testaplikacija;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;
Button button;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttOK);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ring);

        }
    });
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/udajSe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bttOK"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/udaj_se_za_mene" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/poklon"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/present" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bttOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"
    android:text="@string/otvori_me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am still new to this, but I am a quick learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the onclick method align the `imageView` like this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);    

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ring);                     
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
});
```

Comment: addRule gets red, saying: Can not resolve method 'addRule(int)'

Answer (score 1):

Your view seems to have the image set to top left, see these XML tags in your ImageView:

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Are you sure the original image files aren't spaced differently / have extra padding as part of the image itself?

Comment: yes, because it is a JPG with white background, that can be easily seen